# Regular expression missing a match - C++

Tags: regex

I'm using a regular expression to find character entries (e.g. `'[any single character]'` or `'\[any single character]'`) and I noticed my current regex is missing `'\''`. Can anyone help me understand why and how to fix it? My current regex is `('.'|'\\.')`

I'm writing my program using C++, in case that matters to anyone.

Thanks.

Comment: You may need `('.'|'\\\\.')` to allow for c-string escaping as well

Answer (score 0):

Answer: `('\\.'|'.')`

The search wasn't working because it matched the first option - `'.'`. Switching the order made it try to match `'\.'` first.